# Tensorflow-Serving - time measurements in ML model

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have Docker + Tensorflow Serving project. I'd like to check efficiency of single stages of model's operation - get time results when the model receives input from API, when it starts processing it, and when it ends etc. Which Tensorflow tool would be recommended to do it with model running on TF-Serving?

Comment: Have you tried with **tensorboard-plugin-profile**?